# Non empty open sets are never compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Show that a non empty open subset *K* of **R** is never compact.

My professor has defined a set K in **R** to be compact if any sequence of elements in *K* has a subsequence which converges to an element in *K*.

I have tried finding a sequence in *K* for which every subsequence converges to an element not in *K*. I have also tried finding a sequence that itself converges to a point outside *K*, but in the absence of any further information about *K*, other than it being open, I am unable to construct such a sequence.

Comment: How about a sequence converging to a point in the boundary of $K$?

Comment: Consider for example a sequence converging to $\sup K\in\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ (you need to prove that such a sequence exists).

Comment: Remark: For a generalization, see the Heine-Borel Theorem.

Comment: @shiva, how do we show the existence of a boundary. If the question was about an open interval, then definitely your intuition works

Comment: @Maximilian, I kind of get the general idea what you are hinting at. I know the Heine Borel Theorem can be applied here, but since it's introduced only a bit later in the course, I am trying to solve it with the definition

Comment: Your set is open thus equal to its interior and as it is a subset of $\mathbf{R}$ it has a closure. The boundary is just the closure setminus the interior. The only way boundary was open is if $K$ is equal to its closure which would imply it is clopen and thus equal to $\mathbf{R}$ by the connectedness of the real line and the assumption $ K \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: Can you use the fact that an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of open intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $K$ is unbounded, take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that, for each $N\in\Bbb N$, $|x_n|\geqslant n$.

And if $K$ is bounded, let $s=\sup K$; it exists, since $K$ is not empty and bounded. Then, since $K$ is open, $s\notin K$. But there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $K$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=s$.

Comment: I understand the case where *K* is bounded. In the unbounded case, you have constructed a divergent sequence, right?

Comment: Not just a divergent sequence, a sequence with no possible convergent subsequence,  since any subsequence  will also diverge towards $\pm \infty$

Comment: The most efficient route, I think…

Comment: @Alan, yes, I am now clearly able to see it